# How to forward ref a function declaration instead of arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the example in React's website:

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

How can I do the same with `function(){}`? I want to do this because I want to avoid create an anonymous function to help with debugging.

Comment: Just declare your function like you normally would and pass it to forwardRef instead of the inline arrow function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass a React functional component to the argument of `React.forwardRef`

```
function Button(props, ref) {
  return (
     <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
       {props.children}
     </button>
  )
}

const FancyButton = React.forwardRef(Button);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this.

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef(function FancyButton(props, ref) {
  const {children} = props
  return (
    <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
      {children}
    </button>
  )
})
export default FancyButton
```